# What credentials does apache2/mod_wsgi/python3/flask use when the code directs a file to be written?

Tags: flask, permissions, apache2, mod-wsgi

This simple bit of code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, abort
import sys, time
import wh_settings as settings


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def webhook():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        daily_events_fullpath = '/home/[user]/[target directory]/[filename]'

        try:
            with open(daily_events_fullpath, 'a') as fileobject:
                fileobject.write("Hello World\n")

            retval =  """Hellow yellow kitty"""

        except Exception as ex:
            retval =  str(ex)

    else:
        retval = """Not a 'POST'"""

    return retval, 200
```

...results in a:

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/[user]/[target directory]/[filename]'

(with '[user]/[target directory]/[filename]' replaced with valid stuff)

Since I set up an ACL (and double checked it with "getfacl") that allows "www-data" to write to that directory, I think apache2/mod_wsgi/python3/flask must be using some other credentials to write the file.

Can anyone tell me how to figure out what credentials are being used? I've looked in /var/log/auth.log and there is no "denial" entry for the attempt to open the file for append.

Additional system information:

```
Opsys = Linux 
Kernel ver = 5.3.0-1030-aws
distro = Ubuntu 18.04,4 LTS Server (no GUI)
SELinux is not installed
AppArmor is installed and enabled
```

Comment: What operating system and version, and is SELinux enabled on that system? A good sanity check is to write into `/tmp/`, then examine owner and group on that file.

Comment: Hi Dave.  Still me trying to narrow down the same problem.  Opsys = Linux, Kernel ver = 5.3.0-1030-aws, distro  = Ubuntu 18.04,4 LTS Server (no GUI), SELinux is not enabled.

As before, an attempt to write to /tmp/ eliminates the permission error, but no file gets written.  I thought maybe apache was redirecting the write, but a "find" from "/" reveals the file is not anywhere on the system.

Comment: Turns out, the Ubuntu distro does not use SELinux.  It uses another system called AppArmor, which IS installed and enabled on my system.  I'm going to do some research now to wee if that may be what's getting in the way.  It seems surprising that it would prevent writing to a directory for which an ACL has been set up, so, I think it's probable that I will still need to know what credentials apache2, et al, are using to attempt the write.

Comment: If that's the spiritual successor of SELinux, you have my sympathies.

Comment: Lol.  I'll certainly share my pain, at whatever level I think might be helpful to others.

Comment: I used this site to learn the basics of AppArmor:
https://linuxhint.com/debian_apparmor_tutorial/

It was surprisingly painless.  apache2 is not in the list of "confined" applications.  The only app that IS in the list is the Amazon System Manager, and even it is only in "complain" (not "enforce") mode.  So it seems unlikely that MAC is in the way.  I'm still stuck.  I just wish I could figure out what credentials are being used to write files.  With that info I could start the fiddling process to make it okay for apache2/mod_wsgi/flask to write to the target directory.